# Using Array and IEnumerable in an Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm trying to write an extension method like this:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int FindSubArray(this Array x, Array y)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (y.SequenceEqual(x.Skip(i).Take(y.Length)))
            {
                offset = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return offset;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler tells me that `Array` does not have a `.Skip()` method.  Only `IEnumerable` does:

> error CS1061: 'Array' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no accessible extension method 'Skip'

But when I changed the parameter types to `IEnumerable<T>`, it says that `IEnumerable` does not have a `.Length` property, only `Array` has that.

> error CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no accessible extension method 'Length'

When I wrote similar code outside an extension method, with both types as `byte[]`, it had no problem with me using `.Skip()` and `.Length` as it easily converted `byte[]` to an `IEnumerable<byte>` when needed.

How can I write my extension method to use both `.Skip` and `.Length`?

Comment: Change the type to `public static int FindSubArray<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)` (or `IReadOnlyList<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has a `Count` property.

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't have a `.Length` property, but it does have a `.Count()`.. will that work for your implementation

Comment: @SeanSailer And short-circuits to `Length` but if you know you are using arrays, I think a generic method is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks @Lee!  I didn't get the difference between `Array` and `T[]` (which looks like an array as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the method generic and change the argument types:

```
public static int FindSubArray<T>(this T[] x, T[] y) { ... }
```

alternatively you can use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has a `Count` property:

```
public static int FindSubArray<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> x, IReadOnlyCollection<T> y)
{
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (y.SequenceEqual(x.Skip(i).Take(y.Count)))
        {
            offset = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return offset;
}
```

It's worth noting this approach to finding subsequences is not very efficient, and you might want to look at other algorithms like [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: `i < x.Count-y.Count+1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use `Array`, you can. It will not be as performant as generics for most value types, as they will be boxed to `object` and a generic `Equals` method test must be done, but it is possible. Instead of using LINQ, just implement your own sequence comparison. Also, don't start so far that you will run off the end trying to match the subsequence.

Finally, return `-1` when not found, as `0` is a valid matching return value.

```
static class MyExtensions {
    public static int FindSubArray(this Array x, Array y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length-y.Length+1; ++i) {
            var found = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < y.Length; ++j) {
                if (!((IList)x)[i + j].Equals(((IList)y)[j])) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IEnumerable with Count instead of Length property.

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int FindSubArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
        {
            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count(); ++i)
            {
                if (y.SequenceEqual(x.Skip(i).Take(y.Count())))
                {
                    offset = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return offset;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that allows you to use `Array` **and** `SequenceEquals()`. (Though I'll echo others who have suggested that this is not a very performant solution, nor likely the most convenient.)

```
    public static int FindSubArray(this Array x, Array y)
    {
        int offset = 0;

        var loYArray = new List<Object>();
        var ieYArray = y.GetEnumerator();
        while (ieYArray.MoveNext())
            loYArray.Add(ieYArray.Current);

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
        {
            var loXSubArray = new List<Object>();
            var ieXArray = x.GetEnumerator();
            var iSkip = 0;

            while (ieXArray.MoveNext())
            {
                iSkip++;
                if (iSkip > i)
                    loXSubArray.Add(ieXArray.Current);
                if (loXSubArray.Count >= y.Length)
                    break;
            }

            if (loYArray.SequenceEqual(loXSubArray))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

This solution uses Object boxing and creates multiple redundant copies of the arrays. If you don't need to use `Array` or `SequenceEquals()`, I'd recommend @NetMage's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change signuture and use this

```
public static int FindSubArray<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> sourceCollection, IReadOnlyList<T> collectionToFind)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= sourceCollection.Count - collectionToFind.Count; i++)
        {
            var matched = true;
            for (var j = 0; j < collectionToFind.Count; j++)
            {
                if (sourceCollection[i + j].Equals(collectionToFind[j]))
                    continue;

                matched = false;
                break;
            }

            if (matched)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```